# How to debug asp.net remotely on bluemix?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ibm-cloud

is it possible to debug my asp.net c# project remotely in the bluemix cloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, at the moment, the dotnet buildpack does not contain any agent to allow remote debugging.  Your options for logging are as follows:

- You could use a Console logger as shown in [this sample](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/tree/master/samples) and retrieve with the **cf logs** command.
- You can use Console.WriteLine and retrieve with the **cf logs** command.
- You can log to a file and retrieve with the **cf files** command.